# How could the mere definition of a method in a parent view affect a CAAnimation in a subview?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-animation

I have a view that is drawing "marching ants", a dashed line that moves along an `NSBezierPath`

Looks like this:

```
CAAnimation* currentLayerAnimation = [self.marchingBlackLayer animationForKey:NEVER_TRANSLATE(@"linePhase")];
if (currentLayerAnimation == nil)
{
   float lineWidth =  0.8 / self.previousZoomLevel;
   float lineLengthFloat = 5.0 * lineWidth;

   NSNumber* lineLength = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat: lineLengthFloat];

   self.marchingBlackLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth;
   self.marchingBlackLayer.strokeColor = [[NSColor blackColor] CGColor];
   self.marchingBlackLayer.fillColor = [[NSColor clearColor] CGColor];
   self.marchingBlackLayer.lineDashPattern = @[lineLength, lineLength];

   self.marchingWhiteLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth;
   self.marchingWhiteLayer.strokeColor = [[NSColor whiteColor] CGColor];
   self.marchingWhiteLayer.fillColor = [[NSColor clearColor] CGColor];
   self.marchingWhiteLayer.lineDashPattern = @[lineLength, lineLength];

   CABasicAnimation* blackMarchingAntsAnimation;
   NSNumber* doubleLineLength = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat: (lineLengthFloat * 2)];
   blackMarchingAntsAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:NEVER_TRANSLATE(@"lineDashPhase")];
   [blackMarchingAntsAnimation setFromValue:@0.0f];
   [blackMarchingAntsAnimation setToValue:doubleLineLength];
   [blackMarchingAntsAnimation setDuration:0.5f];
   [blackMarchingAntsAnimation setRepeatCount:HUGE_VALF];

   CABasicAnimation* whiteMarchingAntsAnimation;
   NSNumber* tripleLineLength = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat: (lineLengthFloat * 3) ];
   whiteMarchingAntsAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:NEVER_TRANSLATE(@"lineDashPhase")];
   [whiteMarchingAntsAnimation setFromValue:lineLength];
   [whiteMarchingAntsAnimation setToValue:tripleLineLength];
   [whiteMarchingAntsAnimation setDuration:0.5f];
   [whiteMarchingAntsAnimation setRepeatCount:HUGE_VALF];

   [self.marchingBlackLayer addAnimation:blackMarchingAntsAnimation forKey:NEVER_TRANSLATE(@"linePhase")];
   [self.marchingWhiteLayer addAnimation:whiteMarchingAntsAnimation forKey:NEVER_TRANSLATE(@"linePhase")];

}

[self.layer addSublayer:self.marchingBlackLayer];
[self.layer addSublayer:self.marchingWhiteLayer];
```

Everything is dandy.  However, the view that is drawing this path has two parent views.

This View's parent is an `NSClipView`, who's parent is an `NSScrollView` subclass.

And just by overriding `scrollWheel:` in the `NSScrollView` subclass like so:

```
- (void)scrollWheel:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
   [super scrollWheel:theEvent];
}
```

The ants animation disappears.

The `scrollWheel:` method never gets hit, and if I delete that method and run, the ants appear again.

I am completely baffled how this is possible, and am convinced it must have something to do with threading?  Unfortunately drawing is my least knowledgable area of Cocoa, so it's difficult to figure out where to start debugging

**EDIT:**
Throwing in pictures so ya'll can maybe get a better idea of what I'm talking about

Here is before: (take my word that the dashed line is moving around)
[image]

Here is after defining the `scrollWheel:` override (and that's literally the only difference):
[image]

**EDIT2:** Setting a breakpoint on all exceptions doesn't get hit, and the console doesn't output any warnings or anything

**EDIT3:** Dispatching the animation creation and adding onto the main thread didn't fix it